# Databricks Widget Panel Default Settings

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a number of notebooks which have widgets and currently the default setting for the 'On Widget Change' is 'Run Accessed Commands'. Is there any way of globally setting this to 'Do Nothing'.

I can do this on an individual notebook, but if I close the notebook and then re-open, it has reset itself to 'Run Accessed Commands'

Comment: this is still a problem